# Using a File-Based Database with Hibernate and Spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am trying to write a Spring MVC web app using Spring 4, with Hibernate 5 as the ORM for a file-based database, such as H2 or HSQLDB. The problem I'm encountering is that data is not persisted to the DB upon killing the application. Even more puzzling to me is that upon opening the H2 data file directly, I can see some of my data sitting in there. But, it isn't being picked up by my queries upon redeploying the app.

I should clarify that this is not a production application, but rather an educational demonstration meant for portability, so file-based is the simplest.

Here is some of my application code:

**src/main/resources/hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factovry>
    <!-- SQL dialect -->
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect</property>

    <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
    <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCacheProvider</property>

    <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>



    <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
</session-factory>
```

**src/main/resources/app.properties**

```
# Package where our entities are located
entity.package = com.sample.hibernate.model

# Details for our datasource
db.driver = org.h2.Driver
db.url = jdbc:h2:file:./src/main/resources/data/sample
db.username =
db.password =
```

**src/main/java/com/sample/hibernate/AppConfig.java**

```
package com.sample.hibernate;

import org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
import org.thymeleaf.extras.java8time.dialect.Java8TimeDialect;
import org.thymeleaf.spring4.SpringTemplateEngine;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
@PropertySource("app.properties")
public class AppConfig implements CommandLineRunner {
    @Autowired
    private SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine;

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext context;

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Value("${db.driver}")
    private String driver;

    @Value("${db.url}")
    private String url;

    @Value("${db.username}")
    private String username;

    @Value("${db.password}")
    private String password;

    @Value("${entity.package}")
    private String entityPackage;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AppConfig.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        templateEngine.addDialect(new Java8TimeDialect());
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        Resource config = context.getResource("classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml");
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setConfigLocation(config);
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(entityPackage);
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        BasicDataSource ds = new BasicDataSource();
        ds.setDriverClassName(driver);
        ds.setUrl(url);
        ds.setUsername(username);
        ds.setPassword(password);
        return ds;
    }

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }
}
```

**src/main/java/com/sample/hibernate/dao/HibernateDao.java**

```
package com.sample.hibernate.dao;

import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import java.util.List;

public abstract class HibernateDao<E> {
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public void save(E entity) {
        try {
            Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
            session.beginTransaction();
            session.saveOrUpdate(entity);
            session.getTransaction().commit();
            session.close();
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            System.err.printf("Save failed: %s%n", e);
        }
    }

    public void delete(E entity) {
        try {
            Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
            session.beginTransaction();
            session.delete(entity);
            session.getTransaction().commit();
            session.close();
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            System.err.printf("Delete failed: %s%n", e);
        }
    }

    public List<E> findAll(Class clazz) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        List<E> all = session.createCriteria(clazz).list();
        session.close();
        return all;
    }

    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public abstract List<E> findAll();
}
```

An interface and implementation for a DAO...

**src/main/java/com/sample/hibernate/dao/CategoryDao.java**

```
package com.sample.hibernate.dao;

import com.sample.hibernate.model.Category;

import java.util.List;

public interface CategoryDao {
    List<Category> findAll();
    Category findById(Long id);
    void save(Category category);
    void delete(Category category);
}
```

**src/main/java/com/sample/hibernate/dao/CategoryDaoImpl.java**

```
package com.sample.hibernate.dao;

import com.sample.hibernate.dao.CategoryDao;
import com.sample.hibernate.dao.HibernateDao;
import com.sample.hibernate.model.Category;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.List;

@Repository
public class CategoryDaoImpl extends HibernateDao<Category> implements CategoryDao {

    @Override
    public Category findById(Long id) {
        Session session = getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Category category = (Category)session.get(Category.class,id);
        session.close();
        return category;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Category> findAll() {
        return findAll(Category.class);
    }
}
```

Finally, I'm using Spring Boot and Gradle to bootstrap the app and run it in an embedded web server. It's also worth noting that this application persists data successfully with a MySQL server. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Did you try using absolute path for `db.url`?

Comment: And could you try to use `sa` for `db.username` and `db.password` (= _System administrator_)? And what says the SQL log?

Comment: @SanjeevKumar, thanks for your suggestion! I've tried an absolute URL, both inside and outside my project directory, both without success.

Comment: You have syntax error in <session-factory>. You typed: <session-factovry>